# How to make an airdrop receiver? [Swift 3]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, airdrop

I am currently making two apps: one app that will allow a user to input their information (we'll call this device 1) and another that will allow a user to receive this information about said user (device 2). I have set it up to where the app that intakes user input successfully brings up the airdrop controller, and asks which device to send it to, now I just need to know how do I go about making the receiver app show up when the user on device 2 gets the information from device 1's airdrop. I have been searching for this the past few days and everything seems to be written for objective c....

Comment: "I have been searching for this the past few days and everything seems to be written for objective c...."  Does that really make any difference if it's written in Objective-C or Swift?  I had no trouble several months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add UTI to your app, you can read more about UTI [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html).

After that you will be able to get your file in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        your code
 }
```